# python-pptx - How to access presentation section titles programmatically?

Tags: python, xml, powerpoint

In Powerpoint, I'd like to create agenda / table of content slides, with section titles serving as input to these agenda slides. Sections allow one to structure a presentation document. They are particularly useful in the slide-sorter and outline mode. 
Conveniently leveraging section titles for the purpose of constructing an agenda slide is a feature of PowerPoint add-ons often found in consulting (Slideproof, Think-Cell,...). The goal is to change one section title, and have this change reflected on all agenda slides -- without having to touch each and every agenda slide.

Is there a way to access these section titles programmatically, ideally using python-pptx? So far I have tried reading the contents of a sample pptx file with unique section titles. Unfortunately, no success in finding the identical  section titles in the pptx file when grepping through the file contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerPoint 2010 and later has the concept of *section* as a way to organize the slides in presentation:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Organize-your-slides-into-sections-de4bf162-e9cc-4f58-b64a-7ab09443b9f8.

These section objects are distinct from a slide and appear in slide-sorter and outline mode. I would characterize them as primarily an authoring feature as they don't directly appear in presentation mode.

This is in contrast to the notion of a *segue* (pronounced *seg-way*) slide, which is simply a slide having only a title, often vertically centered, that "punctuates" the sequence of slides into meaningful groups. These can be (but are not necessarily) based on a particular slide layout for that purpose, perhaps named "Section Header" or "Segue Slide".

`python-pptx` doesn't yet have API support for the section concept. However, if you just mean using seque slides, then the approach suggested by m_____z is the way to go.

Comment: I was indeed interested in the section objects as one can find them in slide-sorter and outline mode and as you described. Good to know that this currently is not part of the python-pptx API.

Comment: Although python-pptx doesn't yet offer the corresponding API, the section information can be be found if you open the pptx file in a text editor and navigate the document tree to ppt/presentation.xml. Search for 'sectionLst' or 'section name'. Any changes to the xml found at that location are reflected in the pptx, if viewed from MS Powerpoint.

Comment: @PeterLustig If `prs` is a `Presentation` object, then `prs._element` will give you the root element in the `presentation.xml` XML document. From there you can use XPath like `prs._element.xpath('.//p:sectionLst')` to retrieve descendant elements and then use `lxml.etree._Element` [API calls](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) like `.addprevious()` to manipulate things from there.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out the [python-pptx documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/presentation.html#presentations) for opening and parsing presentations. It will allow you to iterate over all slides in that presentation. As you're looking for section slides only, you can use the `slide_layout` attribute of each slide which consists of a `slide_master` attribute that [describes the layout](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/slides.html#pptx.slide.SlideLayout.slide_master) which was used as a basis to filter for section slides. In the slide, you could then iterate over all shapes in a given slide. You can use the `shape_type` attribute to find the appropriate shape - in this case, it would be text box as described [here](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/understanding-shapes.html) which consists of a `text` attribute.